# Url masking in magento

Tags: magento-1.8, url, controllers

I am trying to mask the urls in magento related to a specific module.

```
  http://www.example.com/modulename/controllername/methodname/id/32
```

to

```
  http://www.example.com/special/id/32
```

This should only apply when the module is `modulename` and controller is `controllername` and method is `methodnameAction` as shown in the above url.

I tried:

```
<global>
    <rewrite>
        <special>
            <from>
                <![CDATA[#^/special/id/#]]>
            </from>
            <to>
                <![CDATA[modulename/controller/methodname/id/]]>
            </to>
            <complete>1</complete>
        </special>
    </rewrite>
</global>
```

This is working fine but I strongly think this is not the better way to solve this issue. (BTW, It has many issues though)

Answer (score 2):

Mr_Green,you can do this config.xml redirection.

```
<rewrite>
     <rewrite_featured>
        <from><![CDATA[/\/special/]]></from>
        <to><![CDATA[modulename/controllername/methodname]]></to>
        <complete>1</complete>
    </rewrite_featured>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, the best way to do it is to have a custom router that handles the url.

You need to add this inside the `config.xml` inside the `<global>` tag

```
    <events>
        <controller_front_init_routers>
            <observers>
                <vendor_module>
                    <class>Vendor_Module_Controller_Router</class>
                    <method>initControllerRouters</method>
                </vendor_module>
            </observers>
        </controller_front_init_routers>
    </events>
```

Then create the file `app/code/local/Vendor/Module/Controller/Router.php`

```
<?php
class Vendor_Module_Controller_Router extends Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Abstract {
    public function initControllerRouters($observer)
    {
        $front = $observer->getEvent()->getFront();
        $front->addRouter('vendor_module', $this);
        return $this;
    }    
    public function match(Zend_Controller_Request_Http $request)
    {
        if (!Mage::isInstalled()) {
            Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()
                ->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('install'))
                ->sendResponse();
            exit;
        }
        $urlKey = trim($request->getPathInfo(), '/');
        //split the urlKey by slash
        $parts = explode('/', $urlKey);
        //check if there are at least 3 parts (special, id and the actual id)
        //if there are less than 3 it means it's not the url you are looking for
        if (count($parts) < 3) {
            return false;
        }
        //check if every part matches what it should
        if ($parts[0] == 'special' && $parts[1] == 'id') {
            //get the id
            $id = (int)$parts[2];
            //TODO: add here additional check to see if $id is valid (if an entity with your id exists)
            //tell the request to map to your controller
            $request->setModuleName('module_front_key_here')
                    ->setControllerName('controller_name_here')
                    ->setActionName('action_name_here')
                    ->setParam('id', $id);
            $request->setAlias(
                Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite::REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_ALIAS,
                $urlKey
            );
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

If you need to generate the URL for one of your entities and display it in the page, generate it like this:

```
$url = Mage::getUrl('', array('_direct'=>'special/id/'.$id));
```

Comment: hey. @Marius What are the disadvantage of my solution?

Comment: @AmitBera. I don't know. I haven't tried it. I don't really like this controller override doing regular expressions. I don't feel like I'm in control. I've always used custom routers when I needed something similar and it worked jut fine. I said "in my opinion" at the start of the answer. I'd not saying my approach is the best. It's just the one I like best.